# codeigniter ajax

Tags: codeigniter, jquery

i have jquery script in

> wamp/www/codeigni/js/script.php

and i have welcome.php as controller.and i wana access the method "getOneUserAjax" from controller 'welcome.php' through ajax from 'script.php'

```
 $.post("<?php echo site_url('/welcome/getOneUserAjax');?>",formData,function(data)
{
       alert("hi");
   alert("success");
});
```

and i tried severel other methods can how can igive path  in script.php

Comment: do you have this: `$route['(:any)'] = "welcome/$1";` in your `route.php` ?

Comment: ni i havent added $route['(:any)'] = "welcome/$1"; in your route.php

Comment: hii set blank as base_url and i set index.php $config['index_page']="index.php" then i used $.post("index.php/welcome/getOneUserAjax",formData,function(data) now its working. thax for u r help

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, your jQuery code inside `/js/` needs to know the ajax controller/method url, correct? If so: in your view, **before** you call that jquery code, put the following:

```
<script>var base_url = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>';</script>
```

The `base_url` js-variable is now available to your jquery.

You should now be able to do something like:

```
$.post(base_url + "welcome/getOneUserAjax",formData,function(data){ //etc
```

Comment: I suggest you post both your jQuery and your view's html. I'm assuming you have an `.htaccess`file in place that allows for routing?

Comment: hii set blank as base_url and i set index.php $config['index_page']="index.php" then i used $.post("index.php/welcome/getOneUserAjax",formData,function(data) now its working. thax for u r help

Answer (score 0):

Suppose this is your base_url into autoload file

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/site_name/';
```

Try this one into your script

```
$.post('<?php echo base_url()?>welcome/getOneUserAjax', 
          function(data) {

                  alert(data);
      });
```

and suppose this is your class `welcome.php` and this is function `getOneUserAjax`

```
function getOneUserAjax()
{
     echo 'success';
}
```

Comment: hi i set blank as base_url and i set index.php $config['index_page']="index.php" then i used $.post("index.php/welcome/getOneUserAjax",formData,function(data) now its working. thax for u r help.

Comment: good to know that u solve your problem, i advice u please try to use base_url and set it into autoload file because sometimes it needs to work properly.